# Showing a set of functions $F$ is bounded

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, self-learning

I have a set of functions given by;
$$F = \{f:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}|\int_0^1 f(x)dx = 0, |f(x)-f(y)|\leq|x-y|, x,y\in[0,1]\}.$$
I have a solution for the question so my questions are about the solution.

Let $f\in F \implies \int_0^1 f(x)dx = 0$.

$\implies$ there exists $x_0\in [0,1]$ such that $f(x_0) = 0$.

$\implies |f(x)| = |f(x)-f(x_0)|\leq |x-x_0|\leq 1$.

Therefore $F$ is bounded.

My questions are:

1. How can we deduce that there exists an $x_0\in [0,1]$ such that $f(x_0)=0$?
2. How do we see that $|x-x_0|\leq 1$? I know the Lipschitz constant is less than or equal to one but how does that imply $|x-x_0|\leq 1$?

Thank you for any help and comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $|f(x) - f(y)| \le |x - y|$, $f$ is continuous (and Lipschitz continuous with constant at most $1$) as you've noted. By the [mean value theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_value_theorems_for_integration), such an $x_0$ must exist: The MVT for integrals states that for some $x_0$,

$$f(x_0) = \frac{1}{1 - 0} \int_0^1 f(t) dt = \frac{0}{1}$$

Then since $x_0 \in [0, 1]$ and $x \in [0, 1]$, it is immediate that $|x_0 - x| \le 1$; they are elements of the same interval of length $1$.